# Django OneToField reference to default 'id' instead of actual primary key

Tags: django

I have a unmanaged model Client

```
class Client(models.Model):
   client_id = models.IntegerField('ID', primary_key=True)
   name      = models.CharField()

   class meta:
      manage = False
```

I use `Client`  to extend `User`:

```
class Account(models.Model):
   user   = models.OneToOneField(User)
   client = models.OneToOneField(Client, to_field='client_id')
```

I thought Django will create foreign key reference to `Client.client_id` instead of `Client.id` even without explicit `to_field='client_id'`  because of the definition of `Client` model. But `sqlmigrate` shows:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE `pubsite_account` (`id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, `deg_client_id` integer NOT NULL UNIQUE, `user_id` integer NOT NULL UNIQUE);
ALTER TABLE `pubsite_account` ADD CONSTRAINT pubsite_account_deg_client_id_73086fddd308cd6f_fk_Clients_id FOREIGN KEY (`deg_client_id`) REFERENCES `Clients` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `pubsite_account` ADD CONSTRAINT pubsite_account_user_id_33ed558985f73b32_fk_auth_user_id FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`);

COMMIT;
```

And nothing changes with setting `to_field='client_id'`.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

- Django version: 1.8, 1.7 (Yep, I tried both)
- Databse: mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discuss in #django-dev, it turns out to be a [bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23415#ticket).

While a ticket has been opened, a developer *MarkusH* offers a temporary work around:

1. change `managed = False` on the model to `=True`
2. once you have new migration files, change the managed option on the model back to False
   and in the corresponding migration file add `'managed': False`, to the options array in the CreateModel operation.

-------edit---------

From the ticket page, this bug has been fixed. So if you come to here for the same thing, just update Django.

Answer (score 0):

I cant try right now but I think `db_column` is what you are looking for

```
client = models.OneToOneField(Client, db_column='client_id')
```